# Can't push to gcr with drone plugins/docker

Tags: drone.io

i have been trying out drone and have been unsuccessful in pushing the docker image to gcr.

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: plugins/docker
    dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    registry: gcr.io
    repo: gcr.io/<REPO>
    tags: "${DRONE_COMMIT_SHA}"
    insecure: true
    debug: true
```

The following is the error message:

> denied: Unable to access the repository; please check that you have permission to access it.

I have been trying to follow the documentation but I always get this error.
Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to store your credentials (we call them secrets) in drone. You can do this using the command line utility or the user interface.

```
drone secret add <github_repo> --name=docker_username --value=<username>
drone secret add <github_repo> --name=docker_password --value=<password>
```

Once you have stored your credentials you must update your yaml configuration file to request access to the named secrets using the `secrets` attribute (this seems to be missing in your example). Example configuration:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: plugins/docker
    dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    registry: gcr.io
    repo: gcr.io/<REPO>
    secrets: [ docker_username, docker_password ]
```

For reference please see the following secret documentation which uses the docker plugin as the primary example http://docs.drone.io/manage-secrets/